# How to add a text content slider over full background web page

Tags: image, text, slider, screen

I want to add a text content slider over a full screen background website. I'm poor in css. So please help me to add a beautiful text content slider that describes about each background image. The following is my background page
http://alampady.tk/fullbg/testbackground.html

Regards
Ashraf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And this to your stylesheet

```
.colorbag {
   position: absolute;
   top: 300px;
   left: 900px;
   width: 500px;
   border: thin dotted;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: #ccc;
   opacity: 0.6;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   padding: 10px;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   line-height: 22px;
}

.colorbag span.subtext {
   font-weight: 600;
   font-size: 22px;
}
.colorbag font {
   font-weight: 300;
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

Then I think it will be like 10 times nicer =)

Comment: Thank you very much dear @Nworks. So how can i make this as a slide, that describes each photos in background.